# How to solve "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor"

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle

I'm replacing lagecy's gradle project with boot's maven project.
There is no error, but when i run Tomcat server, the following error is 
displayed.

i tried these....

1. pom.xml spring-context remove -> failed
2. spring boot version downgrade 2.1.9 --> 2.0.4 -> failed
3. i made dependency spring core, spring context same version -> failed

```
Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5352)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:155)
    ... 8 more
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mashape.unirest/unirest-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.lukehutch</groupId>
        <artifactId>fast-classpath-scanner</artifactId>
        <version>2.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.corn/corn-cps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.corn</groupId>
        <artifactId>corn-cps</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-access -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-aspects -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tiles/tiles-jsp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tiles/tiles-servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tiles/tiles-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.bluelinelabs/logansquare -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bluelinelabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>logansquare</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.lazyluke/log4jdbc-remix -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lazyluke</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4jdbc-remix</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibs/standard -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- common-java-0.0.22.jar -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.omnicns</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.22</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/common-java-0.0.22.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <!-- common-jsp-0.0.2.jar -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.omnicns</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/common-jsp-0.0.2.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <!-- common-spring-0.0.15.jar -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.omnicns</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-spring</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.15</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/common-spring-0.0.15.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun/tools -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springmodules/spring-modules-validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-modules-validation</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How should it work?

Comment: These issues arise from mixing jars from different versions of Spring or using incompatible versions of other frameworks (too old Spring Security or Spring Data).

Comment: Incompatible versions or something accidentally marked as provided?

Comment: i added pom.xml...

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you run the following at command line

`mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.springframework.*`

You should then look at all the spring dependency versions. I'm guessing you have some version mismatches which you'll need to fix.

Comment: After entering the command line you told me to build success, the error still remains.

Comment: The command line I asked you to run will list all of the spring versions in your dependency tree. Take a look at the results (append the output to your question above) and I'm guessing you'll have different version numbers of your spring dependencies which are not compatible with each other. `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` occurs when dependency A is compiled against version X of dependency B, but at runtime its running against version Y of dependency B

Comment: From your stack trace above it seems SpringServletContainerInitializer is running against an incompatible version of ReflectionUtils

Answer (score 1):

Posting this because my solution was different and took forever to find.
In my case it seemed to have been a conflict in multiple dependencies having that method.

By grepping my project folder for the name of the method, I could see what jars it was present in.

`grep -r "ReflectionUtils" myProjectDirectory/`

Result: (only listing spring ones)

```
Binary file myProjectDirectory//target/myProjectDirectory/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-5.3.15.jar matches
Binary file myProjectDirectory//target/myProjectDirectory/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.core-3.2.4.jar matches
```

I used `mvn dependency:tree` to track where org.springframework.core-3.2.4.jar was coming from, and it was under a dependency called "org.springframework.beans"

I went to pom.xml and removed the springframework.beans dependency, replaced with spring-beans 5.3.9, clean installed, and reran grep. Result was now:

```
Binary file myProjectDirectory//target/myProjectDirectory/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-5.3.15.jar matches
```

From there I ran on tomcat and issue no longer appeared. It may be a unique circumstance but it was the only thing I could get to work after scouring threads everywhere.